# Suggestions on how to display 'correct_guesses'?

Tags: python, list

I am currently writing code for an interactive game of hangman. I have been given code to select a word at random, which I have then assigned to 'X' and made into a list.

I would like to be able to display a list of hyphens (correct_guesses) where the correct guesses are filled in in the correct place. 
For example: if the word is 'glass', and the user guesses 'a', the computer displays "Good guess! [ - - a - -]" or something similar. 
I'm not quite sure how to replace the hyphens with the correct guesses as the game goes on, or if I should I be approaching this in a different manner.

I apologize that this isn't very well articulated; I'm very new to coding. 
I've included my code below.

```
    X = random.choice(wordlist)
    X.split()


    print "Welcome to Hangman."
    print "I've chosen a word that is", len(X), "letters long. Can you guess it? You have", (len(X) + 5 ), "guesses."

    alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    correct_guesses = [(len(X))*'-']


    guess = raw_input('Guess a letter.')

    for guess in alphabet:
        if guess in alphabet:
            alphabet.remove(guess)


            for guess in X:
                if guess in X:
                    print 'Good guess!'
                    break

                else:
                    print 'Nope! Try again.'
                    break

            break


        else:
               print "You have already guesssed that letter, try again."
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of all the letters that have been guessed, then do:

```
masked_letters = ''.join([if c in guessed then c else '-' for c in chosen_word])
```